# iPhone SDK: How to send data to a server over the internet?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

i wrote a gps-application for the iphone and it all works fine but now i want to send the latitude and longitude to a server over the internet using the most simple way... I have a url from the server in which there are parameters for latitude and longitude. Also i want the lat. and long. to be sent every 90 seconds or so.  How exactly is all of this done? Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSURL *cgiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/yourscript?yourargs=1"];
NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:cgiUrl];

/* leave the rest out if just issuing a GET */
NSString *postBody = @"yourpostbodyargs=1";

NSString *contentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
int contentLength = [postBody length];

[postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",contentLength] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:[postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
/* until here - the line below issues the request */

NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
```

handle errors and received data using:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // data has the full response
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)newdata
{
    [data appendData:newdata];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

you need some variables set up, such as data, contentLength etc. But this is the general outline for http interaction.

You may want to put all handling stuff in a separate handler class, I changed the delegate to `self` so this is more self-contained.

As for timing, use an `NSTimer` to invoke posting the data every 90 seconds:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:90 target:self selector:@selector(xmitCoords) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: does it mean that I have to create a website first?

Answer (score 1):

I think the above answer has the right idea - but try using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).  A great library, and it abstracts all that messy HTTP code out of your program.

Also one other thing to note - GPS coordinates every 90 seconds is going to burn down your battery very fast - are you just doing this for testing?

Comment: No but the iphone's goning to plugged into a powersource constantly and i also built in the option to turn the transfer completely off or extend the period between transfers up to one hour

Comment: Makes sense - just be careful if you're doing any sort of "fleet tracking" and using Google Maps API/MapKit - it's against their terms of service.

Also, is this question answered sufficiently?