# best way to create a form inside your iphone application

Tags: iphone

What is the best way to create a contact form inside an iphone application. Should an html page be embedded or can it be done using only objective c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode has a component called Interface Builder, which is perfect for forms.
Yes, it uses an objective c interface.
I wouldn't say it's the only way, but I strongly imagine it's the best.

Comment: how can i send the response from the uitextfield to a url though?

Comment: Is this thread of any help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275459/iphone-sdk-how-to-send-data-to-a-server-over-the-internet